# High fantasy book series about a boy who's attacked by a werecat, and is discovered to have a magical talent

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

The boy leaves his village with a female wizard. On their way to the magic academy, he is attacked by a cat were-creature, and is infected and turns into a werecat himself, which gives him more magical powers. He also uses a staff for his magic. Later in the series he ends up marrying the werecat that attacked him.

Apologies for the lack of details, I read these books about 10 years ago. Thank you.

Comment: @Smanga - Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and if you recall any more details about the story, characters, cover, etc, please [edit] those additional details into your question. The more info you can provide, the better the chances of someone identifying this series for you. :-)

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

If you read these online, this might be the *Firestaff* series, which begins with *[The Tower of Sorcery](https://offtheshelfreviews.wordpress.com/2017/09/11/the-tower-of-sorcery-firestaff-1/)*:

> Tarrin Kael is a farmboy from a small village with dreams of becoming one of the famed Knights of Karas. Unlike most of those who have such aspirations, he’s got enough training to hope he has a decent shot: from his father who used to be a Ranger, and from his mother who comes from a culture where everyone learns their hand-to-hand combat styles. But when a Sorceress and the Knight guarding her stop by his village, it is the Sorceress who claims him for her Tower. But trouble follows hard on their heels. Disaster after disaster plagues his journey—including being bitten by a Were-Cat, and losing his humanity—and even the Tower of Sorcery isn’t what he hopes. Tarrin is determined to figure out what’s going on. Because if he doesn’t, something’s going to succeed at killing him . . .

....

> Tarrin is an interesting protagonist. He’s only “typical” for a few chapters, and even there, the label is debatable. He’s had enough training to make his dream of being a Knight a realistic one, but no amount of training could prepare him for the physical, mental, and emotional changes that accompany becoming Were-Cat. It doesn’t help that no one really knows much about the Were in general and Were-Cats in particular, and the person best suited to help him is someone he is convinced is going to kill him. And compounding the natural changes that go along with being a Were-Cat is the political game that has thoroughly snared him. Cats don’t like being trapped, or used, and being constantly afraid for his life and unsure who to trust is eroding his sanity.

The books can be read online [here](http://www.weavespinner.net/worlds_of_fel.htm) and apparently [here](https://forums.sennadar.com/index.php).

Found via a search for `site:goodreads.com magic werecat staff`

Comment: Thank you fuzzyBoots..firestaff series is exactly what I was looking for. You are a life saver. I usually re-read these books every 5 years.

Comment: @Smanga You can reclaim your original account by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can accept the answer.